# many-to-many relationship with additional value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have many to many relationship between Students and Courses. I want Student to be able to change position of the Courses in his queue so the Courses will appear in certain order.
I cannot add position to Course since it will be reflected for all Students at once. If i add positions to Student ie. List then i loose consistency with two objects.

Is there a better way to do rather then deleting and then adding whole queue upon position change ?

```
public class Course
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `class CourseOrder { prop Course {get;set;} prop Student {get;set;} int Order{get;set;} }` work?

Comment: @Default will work, lol never thought of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a tie table for your many to many relationship.  This is the natural place to store the ordering of courses because that's where the collection lives.  Something like below:

```
Create Table CourseStudentTie(
  [StudentId] int NOT NULL,
  [CourseId] int NOT NULL,
  [Order] int NOT NULL --This is where you store the order of the courses.
)
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought of this idea. heh

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to store the course to student mapping in a separate table and maintain the queue order in the very same table, similar to what has been suggested above.